# Is there a more optimal way to retrieve multiple values from an XML Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing, azure-sql-database

We have a table in our database with an XML Data Column.

In that column, there's a big chunk of xml data which has lots of application values stored in it.

During one of our more regularly called queries, multiple values are retrieved from this Xml Column in the same query. e.g.

```
SELECT 
    v.OtherColumns --...
    ,v.[Data].value('(/Record//Inputs/Net)[1]', 'money') as 'Input Net'
    ,v.[Data].value('(/Record//Inputs/Vat)[1]', 'money') as 'Input Vat'
    ,v.[Data].value('(/Record//Inputs/Gross)[1]', 'money') as 'Input Gross'
    ,v.[Data].value('(/Record//Outputs/Net)[1]', 'money') as 'Output Net'
    ,v.[Data].value('(/Record//Outputs/Vat)[1]', 'money') as 'Output Vat'
    ,v.[Data].value('(/Record//Outputs/Gross)[1]', 'money') as 'Output Gross'
From 
    Validations as v
    --... remainder of query
```

To me, it looks like it has to read the data out of this column 6 times and parse it 6 times. When I look at the query plan under the Sql Azure Portal, this is by far the largest hit on the query...

[image: Query Plan]

In the full query, there's ~20 of those XPath Queries against the same column each accounting for ~4.7% of the query.

Is there a more optimal way to retrieve back this entire column once in a subquery and then run the XPath Query on the in-memory contents of the column ?

Comment: What is the other part of the query ? do you have unions for [2],[3] etc. ?

Comment: the other parts of the query are some inner joins to other tables but accounting for 0% of the query (so negligible impact) and the tables being joined have been properly indexed. 20*4.7% TVF's are accounting for 95% of the query time.

Comment: There's not really a very efficient way to do this - it's the nature of XML data and XPath.  You could add an XML index to that column and it may speed it up significantly.

Comment: +1 for `create primary XML index` over `Data` column and secondary xml index `... for property` should help

Comment: tried the XML index, but made no difference. IS there a more optimal way to do this. the query is run as part of a report so I'm considered just dumping the entire table of results to a summary table using an hourly job and then querying off that summary table in the report instead

Comment: ah.. hadn't tried secondary indexes. will try that then. thanks

Comment: no, still no joy. tried adding secondary indices for both PATH and PROPERTY and the query performance is still muck

Comment: After adding XML index, did you tried to run query several times? Sometimes first pass can be long (because of plan compilation), but subsequent passes could be much faster.

Comment: yeah. have re-run it several times with different combos of indices (Primary + Secondary Path, Primary + Secondary Property, Primary + Path + Property) etc... multiple runs of each query. no diff. this is all locally at the minute on a SQL2012Express Db.

Comment: Can you add typical XML sample to your question. Also what is the number of rows typically returned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use XQuery statement FLWOR. It should reduce parsing time.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx